# Text / log editor with auto-refresh support

Tags: windows, linux, text-editing, logging

I'm looking for a text editor / log manager of some kind that will automatically refresh a file's contents when it changes.

I have a single target log file (e.g. current.log) that is overwritten under certain circumstances and I'd like to be able to leave it displayed and not constantly have to re-open the file to get updates.  Much the same as 'tail --follow=name' does in Linux.

I'm using a Windows desktop but it's a remote file so a Linux app would work just as easily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get [tail for Windows](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/), a GUI version of tail which implements the `tail -f` functionality you're used to.

If you're looking for an actual text editor however, check out [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/). It can automatically and silently update a file when it detects changes. Simply enable silent updates in **Settings -> Preferences -> MISC**:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php) is a bit rough, and it hasn't been updated for four years, but it's lightweight-enough that I leave it open on a bunch of Tomcat log files whether I'm using them or not...

Answer (score 3):

[Snaketail](http://snakenest.com/snaketail/) has great potential for a solution.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Necro-answering a post I "answered" 6(!) years ago:

These days I use "[glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/)":

> glogg is a multi-platform GUI application to browse and search through
>   long or complex log files. It is designed with programmers and system
>   administrators in mind. glogg can be seen as a graphical, interactive
>   combination of grep and less.

Answer (score 0):

I am very pleased with [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/). It has what you are asking for and a lot more.