# Is there a way to reload a Notepad file from within the application?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad

I have an application that will be writing integers into a file, line-by-line, at a rate of every 5 seconds.

[a sample Notepad file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Kju.png)

I would like to use an program other than Notepad.exe, where I can reload the text file while it's being written to  . This way, I can see the changes easily as they're happening, instead of closing/reopening the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, it is with Notepad++  ( "reload from disk "  ) :

[image]

Comment: Furthermore, check out the `auto-detection` `update silently` option as listed in this posts accepted answer: http://superuser.com/questions/106073/text-log-editor-with-auto-refresh-support